# Links from Outlook not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In the last week, clicking on links from within Outlook email messages stopped working. The links appear clickable, but clicking them doesn't do anything.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is it possible the target of these links is being changed to `blocked:http://link.target` by security settings somewhere, and thus nothing is happening? Try checking your security options in Outlook to make sure this isn't happening.
- Open up a Start->Run box and type in some URL. Make sure it actually opens up a browser to that address. If not, something is swallowing up these requests; try resetting your default browser.

Comment: Your second suggestion was it - this has nothing to do with Outlook. Running a URL from Start->Run doesn't work.

The default is Chrome, but the problem is a bit different: http://superuser.com/questions/153609/problem-running-chrome-from-start-run

Answer (score 1):

I also have a problem with links not working on Outlook 2003. I have IE 8 on Windows 7. IE 8 is my default browser and typing urls in Start -> Run does go to the url.

When I click on a link an in Outlook email a new IE session fires up but it just goes to the default home page, and not the url in the link.