# How do I find what shortcut is run via Start->Run

Tags: windows-7, windows

When I hit Start->Run and type "Chrome", nothing happens (no new "chrome.exe" process is launched, not error, nothing).

When I hit Start (without "Run"), type Chrome and run it, it works.

How do I find what shortcut is run via Start->Run ? When I open a command prompt and write "Chrome.exe", it doesn't recognize it as an executable program.

Comment: I would propose to change the title to "How do I find what shortcut is run via Start->Run ?", mostly because this is the main question you ask, and also because I think this is interesting, and I am wondering about asking it directly. Or maybe keep your question specific, and I will ask it directly, for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the other answers worked, but simply reinstalling Chrome did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the Chrome folder isn't in the PATH variable. This environment variable decides which locations you can refer to without a path specified. The reason it works with just opening start is that it just searches for Chrome in the programs menu instead of searching for the executable file itself. Normally the Chrome executable is located as "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\application\chrome.exe" ("%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\application\chrome.exe")

Comment: But why wouldn't it cause an error if I try to run it from start\run ? When I open start\run and type "asdf", I get "Windows can't find file ...". When I do the same with Chrome, nothing happens.

Comment: Well, I tried running Chrome from the run menu, and against all logic, it actually runs Chrome for me when I do it. Check the .lnk (shortcut) file from the programs menu, and check what it specifies or just run it with "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\application\chrome.exe" (thanks Johannes).

Comment: There is more than just `%PATH%`: Windows has `App Paths`; Windows 7 might also check all items in Start Menu.

Comment: Oh, I've never thought of that, thanks for telling me.

Comment: Adding Chrome.exe to path didn't work. Now, from cmd.exe typing "chrome" launches it correctly, but typing "chrome" into the run prompt still doesn't do anything (no error message, just nothing happens).

Answer (score 1):

Along with the paths listed by Madsen, the shortcuts Run is referencing are listed in the Registry.

Run regedit, then navigate to:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

(this might be a bit different on 7, but I doubt it).

You need to make sure there are entries *(Default)* and *Path* for **chrome.exe** here, with the data field (for both) being the filepath where the program is located.

Comment: and to answer your comment question above re: "why wouldn't it cause an error?", there is probably an existent entry for Chrome.exe - its just not pointing to the right place

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. The registry setting was just as it should have been. Reinstalling Chrome did the trick.

Comment: Cool, glad you've worked it out!